# How to preventDefault event when on scrolling is triggered

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, onscroll

```js
if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', demo);
}
else if (typeof window.attachEvent === 'object') {
    document.documentElement.attachEvent('onscroll', demo);
}
function demo(eve) {
    eve.preventDefault ? eve.preventDefault() : (eve.returnValue = false);
}
```

hi guys
how to preventDefault event when onscroll.
my code is not work.
i want to disable the scrolling, when control scroll bar & press keyboard & scrolling mouse.
i dont speak English well and i'm new to stackoverflow.
Please understand XD.

Comment: More context please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: I could not find it because I could not speak English well.
That's exactly what I wanted.
Thank you.